# data structure for multigraphs

Tags: c++, data-structures

**To make multigraphs which is weighted also , i do following thing**

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct maps
{
    vector<char> weight(10); //to store weight of self-loops and multi-edges 
};

int main()
{ 
    maps m1[101][101], m2[101][101];

    return 0;
}
```

but I get following errors:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant  
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `vector<char> weight;`. Don't initiate member at `struct` definition. They should be initiated in constructor or after that.

Comment: @AdeYU : i don't get you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ade YU mentioned, do not define the size of your weight vector in it's declaration. Instead, do it in the initializer list in the constructor. This should do what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <vector>   

using namespace std;

struct maps
{
    maps() : weight(10) {}
    vector<char> weight; //to store weight of self-loops and multi-edges 
};

int main()
{ 
    maps m1[101][101], m2[101][101];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i want a vector of weight of size 10.how to do that??

Comment: In the constructor, it initializes the vector to size 10.

Comment: vector of weight of size 10 helps to store various values/weight of edges that may be present in graphs.

Comment: The constructor of a vector takes in a size, so when I'm calling `weight(10)` in the initializer list of maps, I'm passing it the size of that vector to initialize it with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the vector in the constructor. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <vector>   
using namespace std;
struct maps{
  maps() : weight(10) {}
  vector<char> weight;//to store weight of self-loops and multi-edges 
};

int main()
{ 
  maps m1[101][101], m2[101][101];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can not call constuctor when declaring a class member. You need to call it explicitly in the class constructor. And from c++ point of view struct and class differ only by their default access(public vs. private).